# image fade on hover + make image clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like it so when I hover over the image, the entire image becomes a link rather than just the text inside. Can someone help me with this?

Javascript:

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    $('.thumbnail img').stop(true,true).fadeTo(400, 0.2);
    $('.description').stop(true,true).fadeIn(400);
}, function() {
    $('.thumbnail img').stop(true,true).fadeTo(400, 1);
    $('.description').stop(true,true).fadeOut(400);
});
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LDs6C/15/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this: http://jsfiddle.net/LDs6C/16/

I made the link a block element and set the dimensions to equal the size of the image.

Comment: Ah - simple! Just make the 'a' a block element. :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Is there a reason why you aren't just surrounding the `img` tag with an `a` tag?

```
<a href="content.com"><img src="..." width="200"/></a>
```

Doing so will accomplish what you need without the extra markup.

Comment: I posted an answer, but I think yours makes the most sense given what I know of the issue.  +1

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to add an on click handler that takes you to the desired location, e.g.

```
$('.thumbnail img').click(function(){window.location='someurl';});
```